# Are Ultegra brifters compatible with 10-speed XT Dyna-Sys derailleurs?

Tags: shimano

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Road Shifters, Mountain Rear Derailleur?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/road-shifters-mountain-rear-derailleur)

I'm looking to build a hardtail mountain bike with drop bars for commuting, touring and some occasional light off-road adventures.

Are 10-speed Shimano brifters like the Ultegra ST-6600 compatible with the 10-speed Dyna-Sys XT derailleurs?

Thanks.

Comment: +1 for teaching me a new word: brifters = brake / shift levers

Comment: [No, because of spacing but 9spd should work](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/road-shifters-mountain-rear-derailleur)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a word, no. Different cable pull ratio on both systems. You can check out [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/road-shifters-mountain-rear-derailleur/6673#6673) if you want a slightly more verbose answer.

Comment: Back to the drawing board...