# Shimano SLX Rear Derailleur with Microshift bar end Shifters

Tags: derailleur, shimano

I need to replace my rear Shimano Deore derailleur since it got mangled up in an accident. I'm thinking of replacing it with a Shimano America RD-M662 SLX 9-Speed Derailleur. The bike I have is a 2013 Salsa Fargo 3. It already has a set of 9 speed Microshift bar end shifters. Will this setup work? The Microshift worked fine with the Deore, but will it work with the SLX? Does the SLX require a different cable pull than the Deore? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This a very similar question (possibly duplicate) to http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/road-shifters-mountain-rear-derailleur although that was based upon Dyna-Sys. One comment confirms that this is possible with Mega-9. Deore and SLX have the same cable pull, they are compatible parts (within the same speed groupset).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this will work. Just get any Shimano mountain rear derailleur... SLX, deore, LX, xt, xtr, etc...

EDIT:

This only applies for 9 speed and lower. Here's a quote from Sheldon Brown.

> Within a given brand/style of rear derailer, all "speed numbers" are generally interchangeable. This applies to all indexable models, basically everything manufactured since the late 1980s. There are a few exceptions:

http://sheldonbrown.com/speeds.html

The exception for Shimano

> Shimano "Dyna-Sys" 10-speed shifters and derailers use a longer cable pull than other Shimano models, and must be used together.

Comment: This is only part of the story. It's best to make sure that the number of gears matches. If the OP uses an 8 speed derailleur, shifting won't be optimal. I'm not entirely sure about a 10 speed, but I think I heard somewhere that they changed pull ratios with the switch to ten speed. If that's right, it wouldn't work at all.

Comment: You are partially right. I'm just going to quote the expert in this case... I was generally speaking of 9 speed and lower within a brand, in this case Shimano. I have edited my post.

"Within a given brand/style of rear derailer, all "speed numbers" are generally interchangeable. This applies to all indexable models, basically everything manufactured since the late 1980s. There are a few exceptions:"

Comment: If you're running 9-speed shifters and 9-speed SLX derailleur, you should be good to go. The 9-speed SLX derailleur has the same cable pull ratio as your old 9-speed deore. Unless you're going 10-speed, you're in the clear.

Comment: usually, microshift bar end shifters can also run friction, in the worst case.

Comment: Unfortunately, the micro shift bar ends do not support friction mode for rear deraileurs.